# Calling a method from object already instantiated

Tags: php, oop

I need a simple debug class so I can add to it throughout the running of the app and output it and see a debug trail.

```
class debug {
    public function __construct(){
        $this->debug = '';
    }

    public function set($addition) {
        $this->debug .= $addition .'<br\/>';
    }

    public function get(){
        return $this->debug;
    }
}
$debugUser = new debug();
$debugSystem = new debug();
```

So i now have two objects. Using the following I can now set a trail for debugSystem:

```
$debugSystem->set('System debug instantiated.');
```

However if I create an object from a different class I cannot use the above, to add to

```
$debugSystem->debug;
```

For example:

```
class user {
    public function __construct() {
        $debugSystem->set('The class 'user' has been created.');
    }
}
$user = new user;
```

This new now gives me an error. Where am I going wrong? And is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: It's always useful to say what the error actually is.

Comment: $debugSystem is not visible in the constructor of your User class. You'll have to use static debug methods or something else..

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution will be - use static debug method. That will be:

```
class Debug
{
   protected static $debug = '';

   public static function get()
   {
      return self::$debug;
   }

   public static function set($addition)
   {
      self::$debug.=$addition;
   }
}
```

and then in your class usage will be:

```
class user {
    public function __construct() {
        Debug::set('The class "user" has been created.');
    }
}
```

however, it may be not the thing you want since in this case you'll not be able to have different debuggers (there will be only one, static global debugger). Also having static methods in general is bad (because they are some sort of side-effect, i.e. explicit context and that is hard to test). So your another possible solution would be to create injection method for your class, like:

```
class user
{
   private $debugger = null;
   //{...}
   public function setDebugger(Debug $debugger)
   {
      $this->$debugger = $debugger;
   }
}
```

-so then you'll be able to use `$this->debugger` implicit in `user` class.

Comment: Ok, i can get around this by creating 2 classes, one for each, user/system. Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

The problem is one of [variable scope](http://php.net/global). Within a function such as the `__construct`, global variables like your `$debugSystem` do not exist unless you explicitly declare them with

```
global $debugSystem;
```

Using globals, however, is not generally a good programming practice. Rather than littering your code with `global` declarations, you should consider redesigning your code so that you don't need them. One way of doing that would be to change the implementation of your debug class to use [static methods](http://php.net/static) instead.

Comment: Globals are evil. Static methods (in effect globals in disguise) are also pretty evil.